# How to edit data in CSV file in R after pulling?

Tags: r, database, csv

```
data %>% filter(primary.name == "Down syndrome" | other.names == "Down syndrome") %>% pull(dx)
```

retrieves:

```
[1] prenatal ultrasound: extra neck folds (nuchal folds) // quad screening: ↓AFP, ↓ estriol, ↑ Inhibin A, ↑ β-hCG
55 Levels:  ...
```

But how do I edit this?

I tried `edit` but it didn't work. Also tried `mutate` to no avail:

```
data %>% filter(primary.name == "Down syndrome" | other.names == "Down syndrome") %>% pull(dx) <- edit("test")
```

Comment: It means that the `dx` column is of class factor and those are the unique values in that column. About editing the values you need to provide us with an example of the data that you have and the edited output that you want.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks! I edited my post btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the object "test" is not created.  Either, we assign at the beginning with `test <- data %>%...` or at the end `... pull(dx) -> test`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     filter(primary.name == "Down syndrome" | other.names == "Down syndrome") %>% 
      pull(dx) -> test
```

and now we `edit` on the test

```
edit(test)
```

---

A reproducible example with `iris`

```
data(iris)
iris %>%
       head -> test

edit(test)
```

-output

[image]